# Is there a way to export each rendered layer as its own image?

Tags: rendering

My scene uses multiple render layers.

I'd like to edit each rendered layer in Photoshop, and composite it in Photoshop.

Is there a way to export each layer as an individual image?

Comment: Just a quick question, I gather this is for a still image and not an animation?

Comment: Correct :) My problem is I'm using an outdated version of PShop. The current version supports OpenEXR... But even if I did have the current version of PShop I'm not after render PASS separation, I'm after render LAYER separation :)

Comment: I hard that @TLousky made a script that works both with render layers and passes. It automatically assing a different output file name based. You can find it here: https://github.com/Tlousky/production_scripts/wiki/save_all_renderlayers_And_passes.py

Comment: Duplicate of http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/33048/935

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can use File Output nodes. Just specify a file path for each.

[image: File output nodes connected]

Comment: *facepalm* I'm gonna have to replace "There's an app for that" with "There's a node for that". I was looking all over the UI for 'Export Render Layers' :P Thanks guys.

Comment: Don't sweat it - I remember I felt the same way when I first learned about it.

Answer (score 12):

Use a [file output node](https://www.blender.org/manual/compositing/types/output/file.html?highlight=file%20output) and save as openEXR multilayer:

[image]

The EXR multilayer format will allow you to save multiple render layers and passes in a single file.

The EXR format is the best way to preserve the integrity of your render layers, as it will keep them linearized and without any the constraints of display referred images (in other words you can keep values that exceed the 0-1 scale).

Saving as [OpenEXR multilayer](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/data_system/files/media/image_formats.html?highlight=openexr#openexr) will help you also if you are compositing using Z-pass information.

You can create as many channels as you need.

[image]

See these links for more details: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/18406/1853

Note: To open this kind of file in old versions of photoshop there is a plugin you can download from http://www.openexr.com/