# Animation render: Save plain rendered image AND composite image

Tags: rendering, file-format

I'm looking for a way to save both the plain render layer frame and composite frame in an animation render (PNG sequence output); is this possible?

Comment: see if this helps you: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/39505/is-there-a-way-to-export-each-rendered-layer-as-its-own-image/39535#39535

Comment: @cegaton thanks Ceg! Wasn't aware of the File Output node.

Answer (score 1):

I simply added a File Output node connected to the Render Layer output in the compositor, as well as a File Output node connected to the last compositing node:

[image: Node setup]

Comment: The second File Output node is unnecessary, as you will already be rendering out a file for the Composited output. This solution will write out 3 files to disk per frame.

Comment: @ToddMcIntosh True, but I was simply rendering still frames at this point and the above method suited my needs.